# Double clicking the cell error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'."}"

Tags: c#, sql

Please help with thank you 
Error occurs as Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

When i "SAVE" the GEM entry form without an "image" it works fine.
When i "SAVE" the GEM entry form with an "image" it works fine.

the error occurs from the "Gem" grid-view which views the list of Gems. 
When i need to "UPDATE" gem record, i will DoubleClick the cell. 
So if there is an existing and if i need to change the image and "UPDATE" it works..BUT

error appears when i need to "UPDATE" an Record which has no image the errors popsup at this line...As the image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stlLl.png)

and this is my stock entry Code:

```
    private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();

            String query;

            if (pb1.Image == null)
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO Stock_Gems (Stock_Type,Stock_no,No_of_pieces,Gem_Type,Weight,Cost,Create_Date,Update_Date,UserID) VALUES(@Stock_Type,@stock_no,@No_of_pieces,@Gem_Type,@Weight,@Cost,@Created_Date,@Updated_Date,@User_Create)";
            }
            else
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO Stock_Gems VALUES(@Stock_Type,@stock_no,@No_of_pieces,@Gem_Type,@Weight,@image,@Cost,@Created_Date,@Updated_Date,@User_Create)";
            }
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);


            command.Parameters.Add("@Stock_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@Stock_Type"].Value = Stock_Type.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@stock_no"].Value = txtstock_no.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@No_of_pieces", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@No_of_pieces"].Value = txtno_of_peices.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@Gem_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            command.Parameters["@Gem_Type"].Value = txt_gems.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@Weight", SqlDbType.Float);
            command.Parameters["@Weight"].Value = txt_weight.Text;

               if (pb1.Image != null)
               {
                   MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                   pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                   byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
                   command.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Binary);
                   command.Parameters["@image"].Value = pic;
               }

            command.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            command.Parameters["@Cost"].Value = txt_cost.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@Created_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            command.Parameters["@Created_Date"].Value = label11.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@Updated_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            command.Parameters["@Updated_Date"].Value = label11.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@User_Create", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            command.Parameters["@User_Create"].Value = hello.Text;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            if (cmbStockType.SelectedIndex == 0)
                _lastUG++;
            else
                _lastMG++;
            saveLastNumbers();

            MessageBox.Show("You've inserted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

this is my gride-view code:
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

```
        S_Gems myForm = new S_Gems();

        myForm.Stock_Type.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txtstock_no.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txtno_of_peices.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_gems.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_weight.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        byte[] pic = (Byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pic);

        myForm.pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

        myForm.txt_cost.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
      //  myForm.label11.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
       // myForm.label11.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        myForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

And i am using an sql server 2014: 
my gem entry table looks as:
Column Names:

```
ID|Stock_Type|Stock_No|No_of_pieces|Gem_Type|Weight|Image|Cost|Create_Date|Update_Date|UserID|
```

Datatype for Image is varbinary(MAX)
i have ticked the Allow NUlls

Comment: If the problem is in the UPDATE code you should show the UPDATE code, not a picture.  Obviously you are not checking if there is a picture first.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: as and intention to "UPDATE" i mean when i doubleclick on the cell from the grid-view i get this error. Normally when i doubleclick on the cell the existing form record will open in that form only update buttons are there, i hope its not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that have no picture have a `NULL` value in the db in that column. So `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6]` does not contain a `byte[]` representing the image, but is `DBNull.Value`.

Your code should be aware of this possibility and skip the image processing:

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6] is byte[] pic) // C#7
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pic);
    myForm.pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
else
    myForm.pb1.Image = null;
```

---

Before C#7 you shoud do

```
byte[] pic = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6] as byte[];
if (pic != null)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pic);
    myForm.pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
else
    myForm.pb1.Image = null;
```

Comment: I just add this code from that byte[] pic = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value as byte[];